# mbtowc returns always one byte on osx

Tags: c++, macos, unicode

I have do search in filesystems for charcters in names which are not portable. For that ich use the mbtowc function to check every character.

On OSX i tried:

// on OSX

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
string s1 = "Ä";
size_t len = s1.length();           // will be 2, ok


const char* s1c = s1.c_str();       // 0xC3 0x84 0x00, ok

char a = s1[0];                     // 0xc3, ok
char b = s1[1];                     // 0x84, ok

mbtowc(NULL,NULL,0);                // reset

wchar_t wc;
int mb_len = mbtowc(&wc,s1c,len);   // mb_len = 1, wc=0xc3 00 00 00
                                    // why only one byte?
                                    // how can i get the right Wchar???
char mb2[10];
int mblen2 = wctomb(mb2,wc);        // mblen2 = 1; mb2 = 0xC3

string s2 = string(mb2);            // len = 1 only 0xC3


return 0;
}
```

Why does mbtows returns for all char only 1?

Heribert

Answer (score 2):

Your program starts in the C locale, which treats strings as ASCII (or, an unspecified ASCII-compatible 8 bit encoding). So `mbtowc()` simply copies the first byte in the string into the `wchar_t`. You need to call `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, locale)` with a locale that uses UTF-8, since your source is encoded in UTF-8 and thus the string constant will be as well.

`setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")` uses the user's current locale settings, so it's appropriate if you will be reading file supplied by the user; however, your example may break if someone tries running your program on a machine that doesn't use a UTF-8 locale. You can instead use `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "UTF-8")`, which is a locale that always uses UTF-8 (I don't believe it's standardized, but it's present at least on my Mac OS X and Linux boxes).

Here's an example (in pure C this time, not C++, to make it a bit simpler). I've added some printfs to show what's going on. It runs the same `mbtowc()` both before and after calling `setlocale()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void test_mbtowc(char *s) {
  size_t len = strlen(s);
  wchar_t wc;

  mbtowc(NULL,NULL,0);
  int mb_len = mbtowc(&wc,s,len);
  printf("%d, %08x\n", mb_len, wc);
}

int main()
{
  char *s = "Ä";

  printf("%02hhx %02hhx %02hhx\n", s[0], s[1], s[2]);
  test_mbtowc(s);

  setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "UTF-8");
  test_mbtowc(s);

  return 0;
}
```

Here's the output. As you can see, we have the string encoded in UTF-8. The first call to `mbtowc` simply copies simply copies the first byte; `mb_len` is `1`, and we get `c3` as the result. The second gives us `mb_len` of 2, and `c4`, the Unicode codepoint of `Ä` in `wc`.

```
c3 84 00
1, 000000c3
2, 000000c4
```

Comment: Thanks that was the problem, stated here.

Answer (score 1):

`mbtowc()` is uses the C locale to determine the encodings to convert between. The C locale always starts out as `"C"`, which is not guaranteed to support any characters outside the basic character set (A subset of the abstract character repertoire supported by ASCII).

OS X uses UTF-8 most everywhere else by default, so `mbtowc()` is not converting between the encodings you expect.

You can set the C locale to one that uses the appropriate encodings. If you do this in a C++ program you should probably do it by setting the C++ global locale (which will in turn set the C locale):

```
std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8")); // locale names are not portable
```

However messing with the locale is generally not a good thing. The global locale is essentially a global variable, and there are all the normal reasons against using it. It has wide ranging effects, e.g. it can effect some use of `sprintf()` deep in some library somewhere that might depend on not being set to certain locales. Also locale sensitive functions may not be thread safe and/or reentrant.

OS X has an 'extended locale support' library (header `<xlocale.h>`) with `*_l` versions of locale sensitive functions that take an extra locale parameter instead of using the global locale. This fixes many of the problems with the global locale. I believe it's even used to implement much of the standard C++ locale functionality on OS X.

```
locale_t loc = newlocale(LC_ALL_MASK, "en_US.UTF-8", NULL);
char buf[MB_CUR_MAX_L(loc)];
mbstate_t state = {};  
wcrtomb_l(buf, L'A', &state, loc);
freelocale(loc);
```

If you only need to convert between known encodings then you may not need to use locales at all. iconv is an API that allows directly converting between a large set of encodings. C++ also has support for converting between certain encodings, in particular between the various Unicode encodings (UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32) using the wstring_convert template and some standard codecvt facets (codecvt_utf8, codecvt_utf8_utf16). You can also adapt codecvt_byname to convert between `char` and `wchar_t` locale encodings without messing directly with locales.

---

Of course all this only matters if you really do need to convert between encodings. It's not clear that this is necessary just to 'search in filesystems for charcters in names which are not portable.' If you have a list of codepoints that you consider legal (or a list of illegal ones) it shouldn't be that hard to directly search for the UTF-8 encoding of those codepoints in your UTF-8 string, no conversion necessary.

Comment: Thanks, i will use this way.

Comment: The localied extension are available on other systems too, also win (Visula Studio 2010: with '_' before the name). By the way MB_CUR_MAX depend on the current console. When the programm starts the consloe will be C and the value will be 1, which will cause an buffer overrun. MB_LEN_MAX return the maximum lenght for all encodings (mostly 6).

Comment: @user1854272 yes, you're right about `MB_CUR_MAX`. There's a macro `MB_CUR_MAX_L()` for use with `_l` functions.